# Cannot convert value of type '(MapViewController).Type' (aka 'MapViewController.Type') to expected argument type 'UIView'

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I've got this error when I want to add a subview. As you can se in the codes where the error appears. I'm 
relatively new in programming so I need help. I'm writing in Swift and without using the storyboard.

Ignore where i wrote:    backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

Edit: I have forgot to mention that I know what is causing the error. I know that the MapViewController is a UIViewController and i put it in a UIView. But I don't know how to make a solution.

What I want is to add a `mapview` to an individual cell

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapCell1: MapCell, MKMapViewDelegate {



override func setupViews() {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    addSubview(MapViewController) //Cannot convert value of type '(MapViewController).Type' (aka 'MapViewController.Type') to expected argument type 'UIView'

}



}

import UIKit

import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

var window: UIWindow?
var mapView: MKMapView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, (self.window?.frame.width)!, 300))
    self.view.addSubview(self.mapView!)


}

}
```

Here is the codes for MapCell:

```
import UIKit


class MapCell: BaseCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    return cv
}()


        let cellId = "cellId"

override func setupViews() {
    super.setupViews()

    addSubview(collectionView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)
    addconstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: collectionView)



}


}


And BaseCell: 

mport UIKit

class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
}

func setupViews() {

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

}

class BaseCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    func setupViews() {


    }




}

}
```

[Here is the new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GIZj.png)

Comment: MapViewController is a view controller... and you are trying to add it to a view... I'm not sure if that is what you're trying to do

Comment: Yeah, it is that I'm trying to do.

Comment: You cannot add a view controller to your view. You can add a view to a view or a view to a view controller

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to add the `Type` of a `MapViewController` as a subview, not the view of an actual instance of a `MapViewController`.

It will probably only help you a bit, but if you did

```
let mapViewController = MapViewController()
self.view.addSubview(mapViewController.view)
```

You'd probably be ok for until you'd want to do something fancier.

That being said, you might want to go through the the OO Programming : what's a class, what's an instance, …

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips. But I'm not 100% sure where I will implement those codes.

Comment: In place of the line that does not compile. By the way, you could have noticed a working example of how to add a view as a subview in your `viewDidLoad` method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Firstly, don't name your class `MapViewController`. That's already a type of view controller, so you should make your own name (I'll be referring to it as `JLMapView`, using my initials) . Since you are trying to add `MapViews` to cells, you should also not inherit form `UIViewController`. Instead, just have your `JLMapView` inherit from `UIView`.

Thus, your class declaration should look like this:

```
class JLMapView: UIView {
//etc..
```

Try this for the `MapCell1`:

```
class MapCell1: MapCell, MKMapViewDelegate {
     var mapView = JLMapView()
     override func setupViews() {

    backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    addSubview(mapView)
}
```

This way, you're adding an instance of `JLMapView`. You originally had the class type in the `addSubviews`, which confused Swift because it can't add a type of object, it needs a specific instance of an object. It's like going to a car dealer, and instead of asking for an SUV or sedan or this car or that car, you ask for a 'car' as an idea. If you're still confused, seriously consider reviewing Object-Oriented Programming concepts, specifically [data modeling](http://searchdatamanagement.techtarget.com/definition/data-modeling)

Good luck, and if it still doesn't work, tell us why

END EDIT

If I'm reading the problem correctly, you're trying to add a view controller type as a subview, which you can't. You should be sending an instance of a view, not the type of object. If you don't understand, that's a separate issue and you should OOP concepts, like [what an object is vs what an object type is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html). Unfortunately, I can't tell what you're trying to do so I cannot offer a full solution.

What are your `MapCell`s? Are they supposed to be `UITableViewCell`s? Are you trying to add `MapViews` to individual cells?

Please elaborate, and I will help you further

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add a MapView in a individual cell. It's a UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score -1):

MapViewController is the controller type. When you type "MapViewController", it's like typing "Int". You're referring to the type, not a specific version of it.

Imagine if I said

```
let a = 3 + Int
```

Wouldn't you want to know what Int to add to 3? In a way similar enough for this analogy, you want to add an instance of a controller's view

Also, I'm curious as to why you don't want to use Storyboard

Comment: Yes, I know why it dosen't work. I forgot to mention that. I saw a tutorial on youtube didn't use Storyboard, forgot what the reason where. But I'm just trying different things and I have used Storybard a little bit too...

Comment: I see. Well as aimak has said, in this case you'd want to make an instance of your controller then add its view as the subview

Comment: Okay, I've googled around a little bit but I'm not sure where to write these codes that aimak wrote.

Comment: In your setupViews(), replace addSubview(MapViewController) with let mapViewController = MapViewController()
self.view.addSubview(mapViewController.view). You'll want to get an understanding of why this is or future work will be difficult

Comment: ok, I implemented these codes do I get a new error : Value of type 'MapCell1' has no member 'view'

Comment: Now I add a Screenshot

Comment: Ah ok. Your MapCell1 class does not have a view to add a subview to. You need to extend UIViewController and add a view before trying to add a subview